# Shopware 6 App scripting cart manipulation in backend not working

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

i use the following code to add a discount to the shopping cart.

```
{% set discountPrice = services.cart.price.create({
    'default': { 'gross': 19.99, 'net': 19.99},
    'EUR': { 'gross': 19.99, 'net': 19.99},
}) %}

{% if not services.cart.has('my-custom-discount') %}
    {% do services.cart.remove('my-custom-discount') %}
{% endif %}
    {% do services.cart.discount('my-custom-discount', 'absolute', discountPrice, 'my.custom.discount.label'|trans) %}
```

This also works quite well in the frontend. However, when I edit the order in the backend, I get the error
CHECKOUT__CART_LINEITEM_NOT_STACKABLE Line item with identifier my-custom-discount is not stackable and the quantity cannot be changed.
What do I have to consider to make it work? I got the code example from the Shopware website

Answer (score 0):

The script you posted has a logical mistake. You're removing the discount if the cart does **not** have the discount yet. You actually want to remove the discount if the cart **does** already have it.

```
{# removed `not` #}
{% if services.cart.has('my-custom-discount') %}
    {% do services.cart.remove('my-custom-discount') %}
{% endif %}
```

You probably don't want to re-add the discount when you edit an already placed order, e.g. if you change the script in the future but older discounts should remain. Then you can check the sales channel permissions for the `skipPromotion` permission. It should be `true` when editing orders in the administration and then you could skip the script entirely.

```
{% if hook.salesChannelContext.permissions['skipProductRecalculation'] is empty %}
    {% set discountPrice = services.cart.price.create({
        'default': { 'gross': 19.99, 'net': 19.99},
        'EUR': { 'gross': 19.99, 'net': 19.99},
    }) %}

    {% if not services.cart.has('my-custom-discount') %}
        {% do services.cart.remove('my-custom-discount') %}
    {% endif %}

    {% do services.cart.discount('my-custom-discount', 'absolute', discountPrice, 'my.custom.discount.label'|trans) %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thanks, that's the way to go. Only when I click "Disable automatic promotions" several times does the error come up.
In addition, the text snippet is not set in the backend. Do I have to pay attention to something? The current title is my.custom.discount.label

Comment: Ah, yes. You can use the permission `skipProductRecalculation` instead of `skipPromotion`. There should be no way of disabling that when editing the order in the administration. Not really sure about the snippet tbh. In theory it should be translated once when the discount is added and saved together with the discount.